# Execution Order in Event Loop

Tags: javascript

why setTimeout(callback), Promise.resolve().then(callback) and
requestAnimationFrame(callback) have different priority to execute?
Following is a code sample:

```js
setTimeout(()=>console.log(1));
Promise.resolve(2).then(console.log);
requestAnimationFrame(()=>console.log(3));
console.log(4);
window.onclick = ()=>console.log(5);
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Comment: what is your expected behavior?

Comment: What I only know is that setTimeout is executed after then callback in this case. And the synchronous code is executed before then callback.

Comment: "*why do they have different priority to execute?*" - because promises are more important than animations are more important than timeouts? Not sure what exactly you want to know.

Comment: I want to know how they works in evet loop. Not just  the design principles.

Comment: @young-trigold What do you know about the event loop already?

Comment: event loop is a component of javascript runtime. other components include taskqueue ,mirco task queue , execution context stack, web api. first task will be executed 1 time, then all microtask will be executed, then rendering.

Comment: So it seems you already know why promise callbacks (which go into the microtask queue) have priority?

Answer (score 1):

synchronization

```js
  console.log(4);
  window.onclick = ()=>console.log(5);
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Micro tasks

```
 Promise.resolve(2).then(console.log);
  requestAnimationFrame(()=>console.log(3));
```

Macro task

```
  setTimeout(()=>console.log(1));
```